# Full screen image within smaller container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying all sorts of solutions offered here and other places, and none of them seem to work. I'd like to have an image take up the full width of the browser window, no matter the size (height scaled proportionally). But I need to place this image within a smaller container `<div>`, as it's part of dynamic content (the body of a blog post). I'm using bootstrap, but I don't think this problem is unique to the framework. Code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="content" class="col-md-8">
    {dynamic content in here}
    <!-- still part of blog post -->
    <div class="large"><img src...></div>
    {more content}
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.content { width: 70%; }
div.large img { width: 100%; }
```

If I put `<img src="..." class="large">` inside the container div, it will, of course, be the size of that `<div>`. If I manually set the width of the image to, say, 1900px, it extends far out to the right of the main content, and I have to experiment to find an appropriate negative `margin-left` to center the image (`margin: 0 auto` doesn't center it). And of course that only works on a pixel-specific size. As soon as the window size changes, that code breaks.

If I set `position: absolute;`, the image appears on top of any following content, which isn't the behavior I want. I also tried this javascript using jQuery:

```
<script>
  $("div.large img").css("width", $(window).width);
</script>
```

As well as a version without jQuery that iterates over the results of `document.getElementsByClassName()`.

None of these approaches seem to give the results I want. Opening and closing the container would be a Bad Idea(tm), as this would break the isolation between the static layout and dynamic content, and so break the whole site if the static part of the layout changes and the blog posts aren't all manually updated.

Comment: Just trying to get an unnderstanding of what you are trying to achieve, Are you trying to do something like this?  http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/immersive_slider_demo.html

Comment: Could you put what you have in a code snippet here or in a fiddle, that would make a huge difference in our understanding of what you want..

Comment: I replicated this in a Fiddle and it worked just fine

Comment: I thought the question was rather straightforward, but maybe it wasn't. [Here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/0zkdkmjh/) where I *tried* to strip out everything inessential, but I may have accidentally stripped out too much. The divs here are wrapped in a few more divs. I'd like `large` to be the full window width, at any resolution. Well, I want an image to be, but the div will have to do as a stand-in. Position: absolute doesn't work because it overlaps the content, and `div.large` must stay within the wrapper.

Comment: Oops, should be [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/crqwbajh/), with the added col-md-8 class.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with position absolute

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
   body{
    margin: 0;
   }
  
   div#small{
    width: 200px;
    background-color: green;
   }
   
   div#fullscreen{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="small">
   i am a small div inside your browser window
   <div id="fullscreen">
    i got the same width as your browser window
   </div>
  </div>
        <div id="small">
   i am a small div inside your browser window
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to do something like this...

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="content">
    <div class="col-md-8 etc..."></div>
    { content in here}
    </div>

    <!-- still part of blog post -->
    <div class="large"><img src...></div>
    <div class="col-md-8 etc..."></div>
    {more content in here}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Set the .container to 100%, the content to 70% and the .large to 100% too

Comment: Then what do I do about the rest of the content, which is not supposed to be 100%? That's why I set `<div>` that encloses the content to less than 100%